# MONGODB update query using subelement _id always returns nModified: 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

My question is simple, but something I am doing wrong...

I want to change all elements that contains a field that is a ObjectId ref.

My object data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a002c0a8ffd1a227c22d71d"
    },
    "expositor_ref": {
        "$oid": "5a002c008ffd1a227c22d71c"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "arduino": {
        "$oid": "59fc5df102b8c20d047cd6e3"
    },
    "quantity": 20,
    "name": "bandejaaqui"
}
```

The query:

```
Bandeja.update({"arduino": new ObjectId(arduinoID)}, {'$set': {
    'quantity': Number(quantity)
}});
```

Debug mode mongodb:

```
Mongoose: bandejas.update({ arduino: ObjectId("59fc5df102b8c20d047cd6e3") }, { '$set': { quantity: 0 } }, {})
{ n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 3, high_: 1509965951 },
     t: 2 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
  ok: 1 }
```

Testing with a normal field works perfect...

```
Bandeja.update({"name": "bandejaaqui"}, {'$set': {
        'quantity': Number(quantity)
    }})
Mongoose: bandejas.update({ name: 'bandejaaqui' }, { '$set': { quantity: 0 } }, {})
{ n: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1509966328 },
     t: 2 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000002,
  ok: 1 }
```

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: Actually `n: 1` tells us that something actually "matched". The reason `nModified` returns `0` is because the value you are attempting to `$set` is already present in the document which is stored. It will only report as `nModified: 1` when the value being set is actually something **different** from what is presently stored in the document. This is by design.

Comment: Thanks Neil Lunn, this is the problem, the element that i am changing is mached but i am setting a new value but mongodb doesn't respond. (The new value is always 0, and the present value is 20)

Comment: You misunderstand. Your "test case is wrong". Wipe your data back to an expected state and issue an update to a value which you know is different to what is stored. You will then see a modified count. When you see `0` it is because the actual value is already `0`. Also note that you likely have "more than one document" that actually matches your condition. So you're probably looking in the wrong place. MongoDB works like it should. Check your test case and see where you are wrong.

Comment: I feel disoriented. I am wiping my data in each request, and the request is only one case, or normal case or test case. Now I tested with random values `{"arduino": new ObjectId(arduinoID)}, {"$set": {
        "quantity": Number(rndm)
    }}` and `nModified` is `1`, but the element in the database continue at `20` but with test case the value of the database change correctly...